# How to create access ACCDE front end after hiding ribbon toolbar with Event Procedure?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have split database. I did an Event Procedure on load `DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo` to hide the Ribbon toolbar.

Now I want create ACCDE version to distribute the front end of my database. My issue is that I cannot create ACCDE version when ribbon toolbar is not visible. Also if I create ACCDE before `DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo` I cannot do this as ACCDE will disable design view of the forms.

What is the best solution for this? I would like ribbon to be hidden as it is with `DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a form that loads on startup then the following code in its `On_Load` Event will enable the ribbon when you are designing forms and disable it when you push a version to your users.

```
If LCase(Right(CurrentDb.Name, 3)) = "mdb" Then
    DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
ElseIf LCase(Right(CurrentDb.Name, 5)) = "accde" Then
    DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
ElseIf LCase(Right(CurrentDb.Name, 5)) = "accdr" Then
    DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
Else
    DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarYes
End If
```